# Как можно сохранить введенные данные в UITextField на SWIFT?

Tags: swift, переменные, uitextfield

Как из `TextField` введенные числовые данные по нажатию кнопки сохранить в качестве переменной, для дальнейших расчетов?

```
import UIKit



class ViewController: UIViewController {

// Оутлет для текстового поля
    @IBOutlet weak var someTextField: UITextField!


    // Оутлет для лейбла с результатом
    @IBOutlet weak var result: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }


 // Экшн для кнопки
    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {

        var a = String(describing: someTextField.text)

        // а вот тут вывод на лейбл, только перед переменной swift выдает "Optional"
        result.text = "a =\(a)"

    }




    }
```

dfgВроде получилось, хотя xcode ругается на переменную в Экшене и  в Label перед переменной выводит "Optional"

Comment: Если у Вас 2 вопроса - то нужно создавать отдельные вопросы.

Comment: Что Вы имеете в виду под сохранить? Просто присвоить значение?

Comment: да, нужно присвоить значения переменным для использования их в расчете формула, а потом вывести  в Label. Момент с выводом мне понятен, а вот как связать TextField и Button - нет

Answer (score 1):

Делаете IBAction от Button и в его теле прописываете присвоение значения поля TextField (для которого предварительно делаете Outlet) с предварительным конвертирование String в Int или что там у Вас. Естественно, тут не показаны некоторые действия со сторибордом. Ну и нет контроля ввода данных, тут вводить можно только цифры с точкой, введёте буквы приложение падает, тут уж Вы сами )

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

  // myDigit - переменная, куда запишем значение из поля
  var myDigit: Double = 0

  // Аутлет для текстового поля (чтобы достать введенное значение через метод .text)
  @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

  // Экшн для текстового поля, срабатывает по окончании ввода (нажатии Enter)
  @IBAction func textFieldEntered(_ sender: UITextField) {
    // Получение текста из поля, конвертирование его в Double и присвоение значения переменной
    myDigit = Double(myTextField.text!)!
    // Печататем в консоли значение переменной
    print("myDigit = \(myDigit)")
  }

  // Функция убирания клавиатуры при нажатии кнопки 'Enter'
  func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    myTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Сейчас попробую изменить переменную на Double и добавить воскл. знаки

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось!